# What is causing my line drawing system to draw lines that fade in intensity from start to finish, using JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

For a school project, I am calling JOGL's `glVertex2f(x, y)` function in a loop to plot one pixel at a time to draw a line. I realize this is a strange way to use JOGL, but the point here is to implement the line drawing algorithm.

Before the loop I am calling `var3.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP)`. Other parameters I tried passing to `glBegin()` resulted in no pixels activated.

My code produces accurate lines, but the pixels fade in intensity from start to finish. Can you identify the problem and tell me what change I need to make to this code so that every pixel in the line will render with full intensity?

```
public class LineScanConverter {
    public static void main (final String args[]) {

        final GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getDefault();
        final GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities( glprofile );
        final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas( glcapabilities );

        glcanvas.addGLEventListener( new GLEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height ) {
                LineRenderer.setup( glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2(), width, height );
            }

            @Override
            public void init( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {
            }

            @Override
            public void display( GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable ) {
                LineRenderer.renderLine(glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2(), 3, 7, 337, 553);
            }
        });

        final Frame frame = new Frame( "Line Scan Converter" );
        frame.add( glcanvas );
        frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent windowevent ) {
                frame.remove( glcanvas );
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit( 0 );
            }
        });

        frame.setSize( 640, 480 );
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }
}


public class LineRenderer {

    public static void setup(GL2ES1 var0, int var1, int var2) {
        var0.glMatrixMode(5889);
        var0.glLoadIdentity();
        GLUgl2es1 var3 = new GLUgl2es1();
        var3.gluOrtho2D(0.0F, (float)var1, 0.0F, (float)var2);
        var0.glMatrixMode(5888);
        var0.glLoadIdentity();
        var0.glViewport(0, 0, var1, var2);
    }


    public static void renderLine(GL2ES1 var0, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
        var0.glLoadIdentity();
        ImmModeSink var3 = ImmModeSink.createFixed(9, 3, 5126, 3, 5126, 0, 5126, 0, 5126, 35044);
        var3.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
        var3.glColor3f(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);

        float dx = x1 - x0;
        float dy = y1 - y0;

        for (float i = 0; i <= (dx - 1); i++) {
            float x = x0 + i;
            float y = ((dy / dx) * i) + y0;
            y = Math.round(y);
            var3.glVertex2f(x, y);
        }

        var3.glEnd(var0, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also add `glColor3f` for each vertex?

Comment: @Ripi2: that's not necessary at all. The values of all current vertex attributes are all state-tracked in the GL. It is well-defined for this draw call.

Comment: Do you have any other GL states set, like lighting or fog or texturing?

Comment: @derhass Nope, no other GL states set

Comment: Well, the issue might be that you draw a line loop, so a connection from the last vertex to the first. If that line doesn't generate exactly the same fragments as your other vertices (and since your vertices lie on the corner exactly inbtween 4 pixels, so rounding might be totally different), the line might appear thicker / brighter at some points. YOu should use `GL_POINTS` primitive type, and if that one is not working, there must be something broken already.